# Regular expression model

Tags: regex

Hey guys am new to regular expression i have found a regular expression like this ..

```
preg_match("/^(1[-\s.])?(\()?\d{3}(?(2)\))[-\s.]?\d{3}[-\s.]?\d{4}$/",$number)


preg_match("/^

        (1[-\s.])?  # optional '1-', '1.' or '1'
        ( \( )?     # optional opening parenthesis
        \d{3}       # the area code
        (?(2) \) )  # if there was opening parenthesis, close it
        [-\s.]?     # followed by '-' or '.' or space
        \d{3}       # first 3 digits
        [-\s.]?     # followed by '-' or '.' or space
        \d{4}       # last 4 digits

        $/x",$number);
```

I found these explanation from a tutorial website ..I just need to know why (?(2)) is assigned here..why questionmark(optional symbol) is applied at the beginning  and what is the use of (2) there in that code ..

Am sorry if this question is of low standard since am a newbie .Any help would be appreciated .ThANKS .:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?(2)\))` is an if clause that checks to see if the 2nd match group was captured.

You should be able to see a break down of your regex at [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/zJ2jV5). It's pretty useful to see what the regex is doing at all points and it's easy to tweak a regex from there.

Comment: second match group means the early matched section ?

Comment: Match groups are what's captured between parentheses. They're numbered by the order of the opening parentheses so in this case it's the `(\()` part which I'll be honest doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Comment: yeah i got it and whats the use of (2) there ?

Comment: i just need to know what second capturing group means ?